# BLAM Camera Calibration Wrong Z-Axis?

Tags: camera, add-on

Happy New Year!

I want to rebuild a picture using the BLAM Addon for Camera Calibration, but using the two-vanishing-point method does not work properly for me.
Look at the Plane on the right side:

[image]

Alternatively i tried using the image midpoint,in which the plane looked good, but the pillar seems distorted:

[image]

Question:
Is my setup on the left side correct?
Did I forget something?
I already used Lens Correction in Photoshop for the Distorsion.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome user9768 :) What exacly is your issue? Camera's z-axis is flipped?

Comment: Depending on the setup, the plane or the pillar does not match the background picture. Check the Images

Comment: Ahem. have you tried moving them to make them match?

Comment: Yes, the X and Y Axis always match fine with the Image Midpoint, but the Z-Axis distorts to the side, it isnt straight vertical. See 2nd Image right

Comment: I wonder if the original image has been somehow undistorted (ie. taken with a large format camera using tilt/shift to keep the vertical lines in check http://www.bhphotovideo.com/find/Product_Resources/largeformat2.jsp), that would throw Blam off. Read:  https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam/wiki/User%27s-guide

Comment: Wait a minute! I'm having the same problem. I'm trying to recreate the Parts & Services room from Five Nights at Freddy's 2 and it won't line up the image.